# Postgresql Dynamic SQL Query Execution

Tags: postgresql, dynamic

I have a function which generates a SELECT query dynamically using some If Else conditions .I have stored that query in a TEXT type variable as

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_updateanswercodes(ans_id_param BIGINT, 
                              que_id_param BIGINT, 
                              overwrite_param INTEGER, 
                              new_ans_code_param CHARACTER VARYING)
    RETURNS INTEGER AS
    $BODY$
...................
................
...................
        dyn_sql = 'SELECT ' || que_col_name || ' INTO old_ans_col_val FROM';
                    IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' profile_answers JOIN registrations ON (pro_ans_frn_pro_id = reg_frn_pro_id)';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' reg_answers ';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' tvl_answers '; --35
                                END IF;
                    dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' WHERE';
                    IF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'pro_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' reg_id ';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'reg_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' reg_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                        ELSIF SUBSTR(que_col_name, 0, 8) = 'tvl_ans' THEN
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || ' tvl_ans_frn_reg_id ';
                                END IF;
                        dyn_sql = dyn_sql || '= ' || CAST(temp_reg AS VARCHAR) ||';'

    /* Here want to execute that query in variable dync_sql
...........................
.............................
.......................
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

But with plpgsql(PL/SQL for postgres) I don't know how to execute this same query in a variable . Please help me with this .
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs (Postgres 9.1):

> ```
> EXECUTE command-string [ INTO [STRICT] target ] [ USING expression [, ... ] ];
> ```
>
> where command-string is an expression yielding a string (of type text) containing the command to be executed. The optional target is a
>   record variable, a row variable, or a comma-separated list of simple
>   variables and record/row fields, into which the results of the command
>   will be stored.

In other words:

Move the `INTO old_ans_col_val` from the String to the place where you `EXECUTE` it.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel can u guide me same in Update query . I have a Update query in dyn_sql and want to set a column value , how can I use that dynamic Update query from dyn_sql varaible?

Answer (score 1):

Use EXECUTE for details see the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Note that you have to take your INTO part out of the query string and put it at the end.

```
EXECUTE dyn_sql INTO old_ans_col_val;
```